# Docker + Nginx + PHP-FPM error: [emerg] 1#1: host not found in upstream

Tags: nginx, docker, php-fpm, docker-compose, docker-machine

I have a docker setup for LEMP stack that I cloned from [this repo](https://github.com/matchish/skeleton).

Everything works nicely on my development machine running window 10, but when I push the image to docker hub and pull it on my VPS no matter what I do I always get this error:

```
[emerg] 1#1: host not found in upstream "php-fpm:9000" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/upstream.conf:1
```

This error is coming from two files.

**First:** [From this Nginx Docker file](https://github.com/matchish/skeleton/blob/master/nginx/Dockerfile#L16)

Here is the code:

```
RUN echo "upstream php-upstream { server ${PHP_UPSTREAM_CONTAINER}:${PHP_UPSTREAM_PORT}; }" > /etc/nginx/conf.d/upstream.conf \
&& rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

**Second**  [From this Nginx default.conf file](https://github.com/matchish/skeleton/blob/master/nginx/sites/default.conf#L14)

Here is the code:

```
    location ~ \.php$ {
      ...
      fastcgi_pass php-upstream;
      ...
    }
```

I say these two files are the cause b/c there is no reference of php-upstream elsewhere.

I have tried every possible combination of adding/removing hosts, adding `depends_on`, changing nginx, php version, disabling selinux but it just doesn't work. I always get the same error on production, but on local server everything works.

Comment: So, that error looks to me like it's trying to resolve what "php-fpm:9000" is, and failing. [This line](https://github.com/matchish/skeleton/blob/f37b87273f2a37ce873abf68c772dba0ff983f3d/nginx/Dockerfile#L12) sets the variable, is there something different on your local machine than what's in production? Are you deploying using the same docker-compose.yml file? From what I can tell it looks like you need to have the php-fpm container running before you can run the nginx container.

Comment: The machine is just a simple centos7 vps, nothing installed except `yum update` ..how do I maka php-fpm run after the nginx container?

Comment: If you're using `docker-compose` add `depends_on: [php-fpm]` to the configuration of the `nginx` service. This will start nginx after php-fpm. Take a look at the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#depends_on)

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I have run into this same issue. Docker compose and my nginx config works fine on Windows, but not when I try to use the exact same things on my Mac.

I have noticed that, for me, the issue only started when I switched from doing `image: nginx:latest` in the yml file to using `build: context: .nginx` and having a dockerfile in the my nginx folder.

Comment: oh man, yes i figured it out but I forgot :) I remember spending days but somehow either i found out by chance or someone told me and I can't remember. But I have a docker-compose for lemp stack which i made after i resolved the issue and now I just pull and run compose and it works. it has php-fpm, nginx, mariadb ... let me know if interested.

Comment: Yeah, if you don't mind dropping me a link to it, I would greatly appreciate it!!!

Comment: Ok, I have been meaning to push this but didn't have time. I did a quick dusting and tested it, it works. Just clone and run `docker-compose up -d` check link https://github.com/samayo/docker-simple-lemp

Comment: Also I remember the error was related to a network. A docker network must be created to avoid the upstream error,  let me know if my repo doesn't work or if it works

Comment: Yeah, in my case, I already had a network defined and it worked on windows, but not on mac, which is why it was weird. On my mac, it also worked when I used image instead of build, too. I'll check out your repo tonight and see if it works for me on my mac.

Answer (score 9):

nginx fails to resolve the hostname `php-fpm` and therefore refuses to start.

There is a simple workaround which - in this case - results in a `502 - Bad Gateway` until nginx is able to resolve the upstream's hostname: Put the upstream address into a variable!

Further you should manually point nginx to docker's internal DNS with the `resolver` option. The docker internal DNS server is always at `127.0.0.11` as to be found in the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/configure-dns/).

```
    resolver 127.0.0.11;
    set $upstream php-fpm:9000;
    # nginx will now start if host is not reachable
    fastcgi_pass    $upstream;
```

Comment: thanks, but this does not work. I spent 3 hours, the only difference is now my app doesn't even run on my local machine. I get `502 - Bad Gateway` on local (which used to work) but I get the same issue on production as well, so this answer actually was a regression

Comment: what happens if you ommit the `resolver` line? Does it still not work? I am 100% sure that the "trick" to put the upstream address into a variable works very well with any container setup. While your problem of the nginx container not being able to communicate with the php-fpm container might have a different cause it's still a good practice to include this trick in order to prevent a non-starting nginx container i.e. upon system restart.

Comment: I actually removed images, and now I am only using docker-compose to install the libraries, and I upload the compose file in my prod machine to install the same libs, so I can have the same environment in both dev/prod machines, because the whole image create, push, pull does not work. I hired someone on upwork.com and he said the issue was with the network, I run `docker create new network my-network` e.t.c... and it partially work but with more problem. So, the issue I am sure is with docker network and not php, nginx upstream

Comment: Adding also `proxy_pass $upstream;` solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

i have same problem, i can solved by added links to php-fpm
like this:

```
services:
  php-fpm:
    build:
      context: ./php-fpm
    volumes: 
      - ../www:/var/www/html
    depends_on:
      - database
    links:
      - database:db      

  nginx:
    build:
      context: ./nginx
    volumes:
      - ../www:/var/www/html
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - ./nginx/sites/:/etc/nginx/sites-available
      - ./nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d     
      - ./nginx/log/:/var/log/nginx
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
      - "443:443"
    depends_on:
      - php-fpm
    links:
      - php-fpm
```